# Why am I getting posts back when I shouldnt

Tags: theme-development, loop, themes

I have the the following variables being populated:

```
$posts = wp_get_recent_posts(array (
  'numberposts' => 4,
  'post_status' => 'publish'
));

$categoryPosts = wp_get_recent_posts(array (
  'numberposts' => 4,
  'category' => get_cat_ID('events'),
  'post_status' => 'publish'
));
```

Now posts should have 1 post, the default sample hello world post. The second should be an empty an array, as this category has 0 posts associated with it.

Instead I get back (twice):

```
array(24) { ["ID"]=> int(1) ["post_author"]=> string(1) "1" ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2015-01-28 20:49:24" ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2015-01-28 20:49:24" ["post_content"]=> string(130) "Welcome to demosite network. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start blogging!" ["post_title"]=> string(12) "Hello world!" ["post_excerpt"]=> string(0) "" ["post_status"]=> string(7) "publish" ["comment_status"]=> string(4) "open" ["ping_status"]=> string(4) "open" ["post_password"]=> string(0) "" ["post_name"]=> string(11) "hello-world" ["to_ping"]=> string(0) "" ["pinged"]=> string(0) "" ["post_modified"]=> string(19) "2015-01-28 20:49:24" ["post_modified_gmt"]=> string(19) "2015-01-28 20:49:24" ["post_content_filtered"]=> string(0) "" ["post_parent"]=> int(0) ["guid"]=> string(49) "http://waters-edge-winetailor.demosite.rocks/?p=1" ["menu_order"]=> int(0) ["post_type"]=> string(4) "post" ["post_mime_type"]=> string(0) "" ["comment_count"]=> string(1) "1" ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" }
```

I get it back twice because I have two loops that loop over both arrays and var dump out the array.

My question is: *For the `$categoryPosts` array Why am I getting the above array back? I should get nothing correct?*

Comment: Just a tip, do your `var_dump()` inside `pre` tags. It will be much easier to read, specially when you add the results from a dump to a question

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your issue is occuring because the category term **events** does not yet exist.

If the function `get_cat_ID()` fails it returns `0`, and in turn the `wp_get_recent_posts()` function uses `0` as the default for the ***category*** parameter, meaning that the parameter is ignored by the function.

To avoid this behaviour I suggest you check for the result of `get_cat_ID()`, and if it is `0` change it to `-1` -

```
$events_cat_id = (get_cat_ID() != 0) ? get_cat_ID() : '-1';
$categoryPosts = wp_get_recent_posts(array (
    'numberposts' => 4,
    'category'    => $events_cat_id,
    'post_status' => 'publish'
));
```

For more information, please see the function reference pages for these two functions -

- **`wp_get_recent_posts()`** - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts
- **`get_cat_ID()`** - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_cat_ID